# How does one implement a subsampled RBF (Radial Basis Function) in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I was trying to implement a Radial Basis Function in Python and Numpy as describe by [CalTech lecture here](http://work.caltech.edu/slides/slides16.pdf). The mathematics seems clear to me so I find it strange that its not working (or it seems to not work). The idea is simple, one chooses a subsampled number of centers for each Gaussian form a kernal matrix and tries to find the best coefficients. i.e. solve `Kc = y` where K is the guassian kernel (gramm) matrix with least squares. For that I did:

```
beta = 0.5*np.power(1.0/stddev,2)
Kern = np.exp(-beta*euclidean_distances(X=X,Y=subsampled_data_points,squared=True))
#(C,_,_,_) = np.linalg.lstsq(K,Y_train)
C = np.dot( np.linalg.pinv(Kern), Y )
```

but when I try to plot my interpolation with the original data they don't look at all alike:

[image]

with 100 random centers (from the data set). I also tried 10 centers which produces essentially the same graph as so does using every data point in the training set. I assumed that using every data point in the data set should more or less perfectly copy the curve but it didn't (overfit). It produces:

[image]

which doesn't seem correct. I will provide the full code (that runs without error):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Data sets
def get_labels_improved(X,f):
    N_train = X.shape[0]
    Y = np.zeros( (N_train,1) )
    for i in range(N_train):
        Y[i] = f(X[i])
    return Y

def get_kernel_matrix(x,W,S):
    beta = get_beta_np(S)
    #beta = 0.5*tf.pow(tf.div( tf.constant(1.0,dtype=tf.float64),S), 2)
    Z = -beta*euclidean_distances(X=x,Y=W,squared=True)
    K = np.exp(Z)
    return K

N = 5000
low_x =-2*np.pi
high_x=2*np.pi
X = low_x + (high_x - low_x) * np.random.rand(N,1)
# f(x) = 2*(2(cos(x)^2 - 1)^2 -1
f = lambda x: 2*np.power( 2*np.power( np.cos(x) ,2) - 1, 2) - 1
Y = get_labels_improved(X , f)

K = 2 # number of centers for RBF
indices=np.random.choice(a=N,size=K) # choose numbers from 0 to D^(1)
subsampled_data_points=X[indices,:] # M_sub x D
stddev = 100

beta = 0.5*np.power(1.0/stddev,2)
Kern = np.exp(-beta*euclidean_distances(X=X,Y=subsampled_data_points,squared=True))
#(C,_,_,_) = np.linalg.lstsq(K,Y_train)
C = np.dot( np.linalg.pinv(Kern), Y )

Y_pred = np.dot( Kern , C )

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', label='Original data', markersize=1)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, 'r', label='Fitted line', markersize=1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Since the plots look strange I decided to read the docs for the ploting functions but I couldn't find anything obvious that was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Scaling of interpolating functions

The main problem is unfortunate choice of standard deviation of the functions used for interpolation:

```
stddev = 100
```

The features of your functions (its humps) are of size about 1. So, use

```
stddev = 1
```

#### Order of X values

The mess of red lines is there because `plt` from matplotlib connects consecutive data points, in the order given. Since your X values are in random order, this results in chaotic left-right movements. Use sorted X:

```
X = np.sort(low_x + (high_x - low_x) * np.random.rand(N,1), axis=0)
```

#### Efficiency issues

Your `get_labels_improved` method is inefficient, looping over the elements of X. Use `Y = f(X)`, leaving the looping to low-level NumPy internals.

Also, the computation of least-squared solution of an overdetermined system should be done with [lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) instead of computing the pseudoinverse (computationally expensive) and multiplying by it.

Here is the cleaned-up code; using  30 centers gives a good fit.

[image: fit]

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5000

low_x =-2*np.pi
high_x=2*np.pi
X = np.sort(low_x + (high_x - low_x) * np.random.rand(N,1), axis=0)
f = lambda x: 2*np.power( 2*np.power( np.cos(x) ,2) - 1, 2) - 1
Y = f(X) 

K = 30 # number of centers for RBF
indices=np.random.choice(a=N,size=K) # choose numbers from 0 to D^(1)
subsampled_data_points=X[indices,:] # M_sub x D
stddev = 1

beta = 0.5*np.power(1.0/stddev,2)
Kern = np.exp(-beta*euclidean_distances(X=X, Y=subsampled_data_points,squared=True))
C = np.linalg.lstsq(Kern, Y)[0]

Y_pred = np.dot(Kern, C)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', label='Original data', markersize=1)
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, 'r', label='Fitted line', markersize=1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't understand why the sorting is necessary. If what you say its true, then why does the original curve in my plot looks fine. Shouldn't that also be Chaotic?

Comment: The original curve isn't a curve, it's a collection of markers 'o' that are **not** connected by lines. The second plot doesn't specify a marker shape, so a plot is made by connecting the dots in the order they are listed. See the line options of `plt.plot`.

Comment: so doing something like `plt.plot(X, Y,'bo', X, Y_pred, 'ro')` would sort of remove the problem I'd assume?

Comment: Yes, if there are no connecting lines, the order in which the points are plied does not matter. Another, and more natural solution, would be to use another list of x values for the second plot, a uniformly spaced one. After all, the idea of interpolation is to expand the domain of a  function.

Comment: by the way, how did you know how to choose the standard deviation? Did you just eye ball it from the plot or is there a more general method that works?

Comment: I simply eyeball it. But if you have decided on the number of centers to use, it's reasonable to take standard deviation equal to the range of x axis divided by the number of centers.

Comment: to generalize that idea to D dimensions, it would be the distance between the farthest two points divided by the number of centers?

Comment: This is too complicated for comments, and seems off-topic for SO. Consider asking at [scicomp.se]. Or Google "optimal shape parameter rbf".